# Prolog - Listing

Tags: prolog

I have some problem with trying to work out my code here.

Let's say I have these codes:

```
university('University of Cambridge', 1, 'United Kingdom', 90.3, 92.8, 89.4),
university('University of Oxford', 2, 'United Kingdom', 88.9, 94.8, 88.0).
```

How do I list out the names of the universities only?
I tried doing *listing.* and *listing(university).* but that list out everything or the rules.

Trying to only get the names like:

```
University of Cambridge
University of Oxford
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you one name:

```
?: university(X,_,_,_,_).
```

You can query for more with `;` or <kbd>space</kbd>

To print all of them, you could use a fail driven loop:

```
?: university(X,_,_,_,_), write(X), nl, fail; true.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, ?: university(X,_,_,_,_), write(X), nl, fail; true. solved it for me.